# TeamCity - How to publish one output dll into many directories?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm trying to publish one of the output dll's to multiple artifact directories. But it seems, that teamcity is publishing that dll only to the last directory.

I would like to have something like this:

```
MyTool\MyTool.dll =>  MyZip.zip!/MyTool1/
MyTool\MyTool.dll =>  MyZip.zip!/MyTool2/
```

And on output:

```
MyZip.zip
    MyTool1/MyTool.dll
    MyTool2/MyTool.dll
```

But TeamCity returns me only last line:

```
MyZip.zip
    MyTool2/MyTool.dll
```

Does anyone know how to publish one dll from builds output to multiple artifacts directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent some time looking for a workaround.  It seems like the zip file is the sticking point.  If it doesn't *need* to be zipped, then the following works fine:

```
MyTool\MyTool.dll =>  MyTool/MyTool1/
MyTool\MyTool.dll =>  MyTool/MyTool2/
```

Another option is to create a build step that moves the DLLs into the folder structure that you want, and then save that folder as the zipped artifact.

Comment: Great, thanks! Also works something like this: `MyTool\MyTool.dll =>  MyTool/MyTool1.zip
MyTool\MyTool.dll =>  MyTool/MyTool2.zip`